# How to append some text to a formula cell?

Tags: excel

I have a cell in MS Excel that has this formulas :

```
=AVERAGE(E2:E165)
```

How do I make the column display the average followed by `" days"`, i.e. it look like? :

```
1234 days
```

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the target cell (or entire column), choose "Format Cells"

On "Number" tab, choose Category: "Custom"

In the text box under "Type:" type:

```
0" days"
```

This will have the additional benefit of the `VALUE` in that cells is still a `NUMBER` (as opposed to `TEXT`), and can be used in formulas easily without having to parse out the "DAYS" text like BigBobby's solution ;)

Comment: I think it's better to use `0" days"` as `space` is a thousand separator in some regional settings.

Comment: Fair point.  I was trying to think if there was a difference between the two, and couldn't think of any :)

Answer (score 2):

This will append the word days, and also limits the # to 3 decimal places.

```
=CONCATENATE(ROUND(AVERAGE(E2:E165), 3), " days")
```

Comment: You can also use the shorthand for `CONCATENATE` which is the ampersand `&`.  Would be `=AVERAGE(E2:E165) & " days"`.